# How to receive pricing for reserved instances (VM) for 12 months and 36 months (1 year and 3 years) via API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to get reserved instance pricing for virtual machines using REST API ?

I am using Pay as you go subscription type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most likely get this from reservation API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/reserved-vm-instances/reservationorder/calculate

With body

```
POST https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/calculatePrice?api-version=2019-04-01
```

And you should get something like

```
{
  "sku": {
    "name": "standard_D1"
  },
  "location": "westus",
  "properties": {
    "reservedResourceType": "VirtualMachines",
    "billingScopeId": "/subscriptions/ed3a1871-612d-abcd-a849-c2542a68be83",
    "term": "P1Y",
    "quantity": "1",
    "displayName": "TestReservationOrder",
    "appliedScopes": null,
    "appliedScopeType": "Shared",
    "reservedResourceProperties": {
      "instanceFlexibility": "On"
    }
  }
}
```

To get

```
{
  "properties": {
    "billingCurrencyTotal": {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "amount": 466
    },
    "reservationOrderId": "6d9cec54-7de8-abcd-9de7-80f5d634f2d2",
    "skuTitle": "Reserved VM Instance, Standard_D1, US West, 1 Year",
    "skuDescription": "standard_D1",
    "pricingCurrencyTotal": {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "amount": 466
    }
  }
}
```

Just make sure resource provider for Microsoft.Capacity is enabled.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work on specific region/subscription type. For example in my case it doesn't work

Comment: I can't validate as I only have MPN and EA subscruptions but you said you have PayG which should work. Just make sure Microsoft.Capacity resource provider is enabled.

Comment: Seems like PayG in my region does not support reserve instances. Thank you anyway